# Is it possible to apply mudtooltip on row template?

Tags: mudblazor

I have a project that tries to add mudtooltip on a table row. Seeking for experts advice if this is possible.

Tried several approach but the final solution is to add it on each mudtd. Tried to add mudtooltip to wrap mudtd but all columns will squeeze into one.

Thank you.